# Why wouldn't getName included in java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject interface?

Tags: java

Why wouldn't `getName` included in `java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject` interface? From what I can tell, all of it's subclasses (`Method`, `Field`, `Constructor` etc) have the method, so it would be pretty handy to have it on the interface.

Comment: Handy, perhaps, but not appropriate or logical.  It is not necessary to have a name in order to be an accessible object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the `@since` tags, it was originally just for accessing the accessibility of the reflective object. Strangely it is not `abstract`. Even though the constructor is documented as "Constructor: only used by the Java Virtual Machine." it is `protected` so, as no `final`, subclassable.

`getName` was not appropriate for the class as it stood pre-1.5. Since 1.5 it has been retrofitted with annotations, which could be empty. However, a name could never be empty and you can't go around adding `abstract` methods to subclassable API classes. Also, if you are using annotations, you probably shouldn't be relying on the name anymore (other than backward compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

I guess that (based on the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html)) the purpose of that Interface is to provide access to the *Access* modifier of the reflection type.

The name is also common to all of them, but just a different aspect than controlling the accessablity. Maybe they could have provided something like a `NameableObject` interface that provides access to the name of that object. I cannot tell you why they didn't, but I understand the desicion to leave the aspect out of the `AccessibleObject` interface.